# NSMutableString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to make a atm machine for a game on iPhone.
I have the custom atm buttons setup, button can't figure out how
to add a star in a label each time a button is pressed.
So four presses leaves `****` (four stars) in the label. I prefer not to
use the secure option in a textfield, as it shows pressed
number shortly.
I know i have to use a NSMutableString and UILabel.
Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Have you tried it? This sort of question is much easier to answer with some code that shows how far you've gotten.

Answer (score 2):

I think this should work.

```
-(IBAction) buttonPressed
{
    yourLabel.text = [yourLabel.text stringByAppendingString:@"*"];
}
```

Comment: Or `yourLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"*%@", yourLabel.text];` or a dozen other options.